# Save multiple raster files as shapefiles

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, export

I am trying to reproject multiple raster layers and then save the resultant images as shapefiles. I seem to be getting an error this error - inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE. Below is the code.

```
outpath <- "output/path"

setwd("X:/input/patht") 

files <- list.files(pattern=".tif") 

outfiles <- paste0(outpath, files)

for(i in 1:length(files)) {

  r <-raster(files[i])

  newproj <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 ")

  rWGS <-  projectRaster(r, crs= newproj, res= 0.00012603363)

  rc1 <- writeOGR(rWGS, outfiles[i], driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite=TRUE)

}
```

Comment: You can't save raster files as vectors. You can vectorize rasters and save the result as shapefile but you can't convert tiff image directly into shapefile.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @user30184. I missed out the rasterToPolygon bit.

Answer (score 2):

Raster files, like tiff images, cannot be directly converted into vector formats. However, it is possible to convert each pixel into small rectangular polygon and save the polygons as vectors into some vector format like shapefile. Some utility programs, like gdal_polygonize https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html, can do a little bit more and merge adjacent pixel-polygons into larger polygons if they have the same pixel values.

The R function to use for converting pixels into polygons is  rasterToPolygons https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.3-7/topics/rasterToPolygons